# How to handle Symbolic Links and Junction while deleting or coping a folder tree

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I had task to copy and delete a huge folder using win32 api (C++), I am using the Code Guru recurisive directory deletion code, which works well, but there arises certain question.

[RemoveDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> **Million thanks to Lerooooy Jenkins for pointing it.**
>
> The link to CodeGuru for recursive deletes doesn't correctly handle
>   symbolic links/junctions.  Given that a reparse point could point
>   anywhere (even network drives), you need to be careful when deleting
>   recursively and only delete the symbolic link/junction and not what it
>   points at.  The correct way to handle this situation is to detect
>   reparse points (via GetFileAttributes()) and NOT traverse it as a
>   subdirectory.

So my question is how to actually handle Symbolic Links and Junction while deleting or coping a folder tree.

For the shake of question here is the source code of CodeGuru Directory Deletion

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>


int DeleteDirectory(const std::string &refcstrRootDirectory,
                    bool              bDeleteSubdirectories = true)
{
  bool            bSubdirectory = false;       // Flag, indicating whether
                                               // subdirectories have been found
  HANDLE          hFile;                       // Handle to directory
  std::string     strFilePath;                 // Filepath
  std::string     strPattern;                  // Pattern
  WIN32_FIND_DATA FileInformation;             // File information


  strPattern = refcstrRootDirectory + "\\*.*";
  hFile = ::FindFirstFile(strPattern.c_str(), &FileInformation);
  if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    do
    {
      if(FileInformation.cFileName[0] != '.')
      {
        strFilePath.erase();
        strFilePath = refcstrRootDirectory + "\\" + FileInformation.cFileName;

        if(FileInformation.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
          if(bDeleteSubdirectories)
          {
            // Delete subdirectory
            int iRC = DeleteDirectory(strFilePath, bDeleteSubdirectories);
            if(iRC)
              return iRC;
          }
          else
            bSubdirectory = true;
        }
        else
        {
          // Set file attributes
          if(::SetFileAttributes(strFilePath.c_str(),
                                 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL) == FALSE)
            return ::GetLastError();

          // Delete file
          if(::DeleteFile(strFilePath.c_str()) == FALSE)
            return ::GetLastError();
        }
      }
    } while(::FindNextFile(hFile, &FileInformation) == TRUE);

    // Close handle
    ::FindClose(hFile);

    DWORD dwError = ::GetLastError();
    if(dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
      return dwError;
    else
    {
      if(!bSubdirectory)
      {
        // Set directory attributes
        if(::SetFileAttributes(refcstrRootDirectory.c_str(),
                               FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL) == FALSE)
          return ::GetLastError();

        // Delete directory
        if(::RemoveDirectory(refcstrRootDirectory.c_str()) == FALSE)
          return ::GetLastError();
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}


int main()
{
  int         iRC                  = 0;
  std::string strDirectoryToDelete = "c:\\mydir";


  // Delete 'c:\mydir' without deleting the subdirectories
  iRC = DeleteDirectory(strDirectoryToDelete, false);
  if(iRC)
  {
    std::cout << "Error " << iRC << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  // Delete 'c:\mydir' and its subdirectories
  iRC = DeleteDirectory(strDirectoryToDelete);
  if(iRC)
  {
    std::cout << "Error " << iRC << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  // Wait for keystroke
  _getch();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DeleteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to delete file symbolic links.

Use [`RemoveDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to delete directory symbolic links and junctions.

In other words, you treat them just like any other file or directory except that you don't recurse into directories that have the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT` attribute.

Comment: while enumerating the folder tree, have to check the dwFileAttribute for FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT for both file and folder, for file have to use DeleteFile and for folders have to use RemoveDirectory. Am i right,  Is there any other thing to consider while deleting a folder tree unlike FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT. And does FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT has to be considered while moving a folder from one location to another using win32 code.

Comment: That's right.  You are already using DeleteFile for files and RemoveDirectory for directories so the only thing you have to change is whether you recurse or not.  I can't think of anything else you need to worry about.  You can move a folder with a single API call (MoveFileEx) so you don't need to worry about the folder contents.

Comment: I cannot use MoveFileEx, so my concern is that, if i use the same method for copying the directory tree, then if i encounter hte FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT then do i have to recurse it or only copy the Folder.

Comment: You could plausibly do either.  It's up to you.  However, note that normal users by default don't have permission to create symbolic links.  Also, this is a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve your goal, and the recommended way to do it, is to get the system to do the work.

- If you need to support XP then you use [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx) with the `FO_DELETE` flag.
- Otherwise, for Vista and later, use [`IFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771.aspx).

These APIs handle all the details for you, and use the same code paths as does the shell. You can even show the standard shell progress UI if you desire.

Comment: i cannot use it, because i have to log every detail with progress, so i had to follow the above routine, my concern was mainly with FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT, whether it is copy or delete, the delete part is confirmed now, only copy parts remains

Comment: @Rahul IFileOperation gives you that

Comment: i have not found any sample how to use IFileOperation to save log of each file and with progress to progressbar

Comment: You supply a IFileOperationProgressSink interface that gets all the progress notifications

Comment: its really cool, but my admin has restricted me in using IFileOperation he wants me to use the above method only, i don't know what he is upto, sir, do i have to recurse the Directory if it has FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT or not. This will clear my doubts.

Comment: @Rahul You are welcome to do it however you like. However, the methods I describe are still, I feel, the best way to do it. The fact that your admin cannot recognise a good thing doesn't really change anything from my perspective.